# Reasoning the Integral test for convergence in forms of variables

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

First I have to apologize for the formatting if not displaying correctly, as this is my first post on this site, polishing is perhaps required.

*Edited. Thanks, m8

I've encountered a question, which requires to show that
$$\int^{b}_{a} \frac{1}{(b-x)^{p}}dx=\begin{cases}\infty& p\geq 1\\\dfrac{(b-a)^{(1-p)}}{(1-p)}&p < 1\end{cases}$$

My approach was to substitute the upper bound, as $b - x = u$ (since the integral reaches $\infty$ when $b = x$, and so is the vertical asymptote located at).

And express the function into the form alike $$\int^{\infty}_{1} \frac{1}{x^{p}}dx$$

which later converted into limit function.

As I process to the part

$-\lim_{b \rightarrow x^-} {\dfrac{u^{-p+1}} {-p+1}}]^{u=b}_{u=a}$　, I couldn't advance any further for reforming into the ideal form.

Please help me to indicate that from which step was incorrect for expressing the function.

It's quite frustrating for dealing the functions with multiple variables, only for the sake of generating the general form manually.

Also, sorry for improper grammar if existed from a non-native speaker, Grammarly wasn't applied for posting this question.